# ListViewItem text truncated after selection - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` with some `ListViewItems` (only text).

```
listView1 = new ListView
{
    View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details,
    HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None
};


listView1.Columns.Add(String.Empty, -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

The following image is an example:

[image]

The problem is that when I select one of these items the text is truncated, like in the following image:

[image]

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could this be due to the width of the column being set to -2?  Do you have a specific reason for doing that?

Comment: It may make a difference to set the `ColumnHeader header;` `header.Width` property to something else, maybe throw it in `SelectionChanged{}( header.Width = listView.SelectedItem(0).Length;`

Comment: @MartinParkin -2 because I want that the column occupies all the space available (no vertical line).

Comment: What version of the Compact Framework?  What is the target platform (WinCE, WinMo, etc)?

Comment: @ctacke Compact Framework 3.5 and Windows Mobile 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Text of your ListViewItem ends with empty spaces. You have to TrimEnd the string and you have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may make a difference to set:

```
ColumnHeader header;
```

then, the `header.Width` property to something else, maybe throw it in

```
SelectionChanged{}(  
    header.Width = listView.SelectedItem(0).Length;
)
```

Give it a shot.  I'm just thinking that the header / column width is playing tricks with how it's defaulted, or potentially set by you with the `-2`

This link may help with ColumnHeaders: [MSDN ColumnHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

---

EDIT:

So I have reviewed some of the CompactFramework stuff.

[This Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/37eb54c6-4e7c-454a-af66-b5a884c07b68/) seems to be relevant to the same issue.

Try setting your ColumnWidth property to `-1`

```
listView1.Columns.Add(String.Empty, -1, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

That should set it to the widest value in the column.  I do see the -2 options should work, but try -1, just to see if it makes a difference.

**Double Edit:**

**Our comments have been moved into a `Chat / Discussion`, although we have been unable to figure out what is causing this.  If anyone has suggestions or knows a fix, please inform us!**

Comment: Oh, noooo!  Hrm, that's a shame, I'll see if I can find anything else, should have realized it was for the Compact.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything, I have only one more vertical line (that i don't want to see).

Comment: When are the columns being set?  Are they being set at RunTime, or afterwards?  It sounds like the compiler is setting them at the wrong time, either before they are needed, then the data is placed and it's not being resized, or after `RunTime` and the columns are initialized at a fixed size (the default, as no values are added yet), then the values get added, but the size is remaining the same.

Comment: AND!  Are you initializing these with `String.Empty`?  That may be why these guys are still staying fixed in size, as the ColumnWidth is staying at the size of String.Empty, as that's what it was initially set at.

Comment: I add the column in the constructor of the UserControl that contains the ListView. The header of the column is an empty string.

Comment: Gotcha, that sounds like it should do the trick, as the constructor will, well, construct...  Have you tried setting `String.Empty` to `Imagine`?  I understand that you want your Columns to be added dynamically, on a `need` basis, but what I'm thinking is that the `String.Empty` is what's interfering.  Check what happens when you hardwire the column that is having trouble in.  If it doesn't truncate it when it's selected, it's the `String.Empty`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26565/discussion-between-plast1k-and-nick)

Answer (score 0):

Use this column size logic instead:

```
listView1.Columns[0].Width = listView1.Width;
```

Comment: Please let us know if this works!  And if you have any idea why this fixes it :]

Comment: I doesn't work. I don't know why but my listView1.Columns[0].Width is 460 in the SelectionChanged event (instead of -2). My listView1.Width is 464, so if I add this code in the event i can see the horizzontal scroll bar, but the text is still truncated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change manually the width of the column. Go in designer mode and change it manually. Just drag it

Comment: The problem is not the column width (that is always the same).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Selected item style . . .
The selected item Textwrapping="Wrap" or Increasing selected item column width.
I think only problem with this two.